# How to retrieve every part of an email except from attachments

Tags: javascript, node.js, imap

I'm currently using [node-imap](https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap) in order to try to retrieve emails from a central server.  Unfortunately, I'm struggling to retrieve emails from the server without any attachments but still retrieving the HTML & text body components.  At the moment I'm using:

```
{
  bodies: '', 
  struct: true, 
  envelope: true
}
```

In order to specify the parts I need.  This gets every part of the email, however and some of them have attachments >50mb.  I've tried to limit it to just the body using the 'TEXT' component:

```
{
  bodies: 'TEXT', 
  struct: true, 
  envelope: true
}
```

But that appears to not retrieve the HTML body of the email.  Is there a way to retrieve everything except the attachment from an email?

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the structure and loop over that, see which ones are small enough and/or have the right content-type. Then download those.

Mail doesn't have a strong "attachment" status. There are bodyparts, and they can be declared to be attachments using a field called `content-disposition` that was defined a few years later, but lots of people don't bother sending a `content-disposition`. So I suspect you'll end up filtering on type and size.